# How to change the field value depending upon another field value in ODOOv10?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

In my project `hr.employee` employee records are in other model with name and birthday fields , if i make change in `hr.employee` records name, birthday fields that automatically impact on my new model records.how to write code for that, please help me.

Comment: You can use api depend for this scene. In that api use that kind of field where you want to do changes as you mentioned.

Comment: @api.model
    def write(self, vals):
        record = super(Employee, self).write(vals) 
        if record.name  and record.birthday:
            self.env['hr.birthday'].write({
                'name': record.name,
                'birthday_date': record.birthday,
                'phone':record.mobile_phone,
                'email':record.work_email
            })
        return record

Comment: it's not working, showing eror

Comment: Please, show the code of your models and I will write an example for you

Comment: @api.model def write(self, vals): record = super(Employee, self).write(vals) if record.name and record.birthday: self.env['hr.birthday'].write({ 'name': record.name, 'birthday_date': record.birthday, 'phone':record.mobile_phone, 'email':record.work_email }) return record

Answer (score 1):

You can use `related` fields:

```
class NewModdel(models.Model):
_name = "new.model"

employee_id = fields.Many2one("hr.employee", string="Employee")

employee_name = fields.Char("Name", related="employee_id.name")
birthday = fields.Date("Birthday", related="employee_id.birthday")
```

You can find doc at [related-field](http://odoo-new-api-guide-line.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fields.html#related-field)

Comment: employee_id and employee_name both prints same value@zety

Comment: @Naveen Sorry to be so late, `Many2one` field get by default the value of `name` field in case you did not use `_rec_name` to specify another field. In our example `employee_name` get the value of `name` field of a given employee.